# Pass Command Line Arguments With Quotation Marks

Tags: batch-file

My batch script runs another batch script and passes command line arguments to it.

**My Problem:** If my command line arguments contain quotation marks then the whole `START` command fails. I need to use quotation marks because my argument contains white space.

The error is:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Whats going wrong and how can I fix this so I can pass cmd line args with quotation marks in them?

```
REM The below command works fine
start "" /B "Copy_To_Drive.bat" C:/PATH_NO_SPACES f:\

REM The below command fails with the error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
start "" /B "Copy_To_Drive.bat" "C:/PATH WITH SPACES" f:\
```

Comment: Can you try doubling or tripling the quotes?  e.g. `start "" /B "Copy_To_Drive.bat" ""C:/PATH WITH SPACES"" f:\ `

Comment: @Rufflewind no same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with quotes. You have a switch character (`/`) instead of a backslash (`\`) in your path. Explorer fixes mistakes like that but CMD doesn't.

Comment: Forward slash. Dos had an API function and version 5 had a setting to set the switch character.